# Spell-Corrector using Statistical machine learning or NLP

Tags: lucene, machine-learning

First of all thanks to all of you for answering.Here is my problem:

Consider 2 users who are texting each other:

First: **Thr** is no prob!!

Second: Yeah!! I know **der** is no prob.      (**prob** for **problem**)

Both the users are different and one is using **thr** for **There** and the other is using **der**. Many other users may use something else too. I have been searching and gone through:

1) Apache Lucene

2) Jazzy

3) Hidden Markov Models

4) N-grams, etc.....

5) Phonetics

6) Python ntlk

There is one more problem:

The sentences may not be proper sentences. Consider these:

1) gimme hi 5 !!!  for **Give me high five**

2) ssly? for **Seriously ?**

3) Wat r u doin? neways see ya 2morrow for **What are you doing? Anyways see you tomorrow.**

Again a different user may using something different for the above words also the sentences may not be grammatically correct. Sometimes it is really difficult to think of a context. The point is what a user may use is very specific to user.

So my question is how do I train my software/application so that it learns differently for each user(consider the case of **thr** and **der**) depending upon what user is using and suggesting the correction(eg **There** for **thr** for one user and **There** for **der** for the other). There are so many possibilities that I am not able to fit it in a single approach. Please suggest.

Comment: Very broad question with a lot of information online, start here for example: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: @IVlad I have already one through Peter Norvig's article and I have also studied a Java Implementation of the same but I am still not able to understand how to start solving this problem - How to make my model learn for each user(that too when there may not be proper sentences and words). Thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: @IVlad Also I have gone through every possible stackoverflow question related to it. I have also one through Lucene, solr, Dictionary API in android, etc but I am not able to find a suitable answer to my problem. The point is that I have to learn from my user what he/she types and suggest him. It is not like Google where they have lots of content to predict the correction and also millions of users providing feedback for the same. So I am stuck where to start.